# Trouble creating ArcSDE Connection File

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I'm having trouble creating a ArcSDE Connection File.  When I bring up the GP tool to do this, I enter the folder I was save the sde file to, enter an name for the file 'MySDEConnect.sde', enter the Server name 'VirtualXP-64180\SQLEXPRESS', enter the Port number I found under SQL Config Manager>SQL Native Client 10.0 Config>Client Protocols>TCP/IP Properties>Default Port which is "1433".  I enter ArcSDE database name "MySDEDB" and uncheck Database authentication since I have not entered any username/password for the SQL Express database.

After I enter in the port number in the Service textbox, it shows a Caution sign by the Server saying it can't connect to it.  Could I have the port number wrong, if so where do I find the correct one.  Any help or direction here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a connection file to an SDE Workgroup database with the following steps:

- In ArcCatalog, create a new database server connection by expanding `Database Servers` and launching the `Add Database Server` wizard.  Type the name of the database server and the instance (in your case `VirtualXP-64180\SQLEXPRESS` and click OK)
- Double click on the connection and once connected right click on the database name (in your case `MySDEDB`), then click `Save Connection`
- Expand `Database Connections` in ArcCatalog, and you should see a new connection called `Connection to VirtualXP-64180`.  Right click on the connection and click Properties.  The connection name will contain the full path to your .sde connection.  In my case, the path was: `C:\Users\sasa\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcCatalog\Connection to sasa_sqlexpress.sde`

You can copy the .sde connection to wherever desired and use it as a connection file.

Comment: I definitely tried 5151 and have had not luck with that.  Still won't connect even though my connection under Database Servers works fine.  I definitely haven't changed any ports.  I tried entering "esri_sde  5151/tcp" in the services file and that didn't help at all.  This is SQL Server Express.  Not sure what to do now.

Comment: The connection file you are trying to create is ONLY for Enterprise ArcSDE databases connecting to Sql Server, Oracle, etc.  As you are running a SDE Workgroup database, you will not be able to use the toolbox you are trying to use to create a connection file.  I'm not sure if you can actually create connection files for Workgroup SDE.  You can connect tot he database server through ArcCatalog by expanding `Database Servers` and opening the `Add Database Server` wizard.

Comment: @willbev: I've fixed my answer to show you how you can connect to an SDE Workgroup database and save the connection to a .sde file.  You can't use the toolbox you were trying to use, but the steps above will give you the same connection file you require.