# Define Workspace for SDE Connection in Python

Tags: python, enterprise-geodatabase

How do we define SDE Connection for workspace in Python Scripting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one access a featurelayer in SDE via Python?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5540/how-does-one-access-a-featurelayer-in-sde-via-python)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

D.E.Wright just beat me to it, he's right on, use a connection just like in ArcCatalog. But here's my take, done at the Python prompt in ArcMap, using the direct full path to a sde connection file:

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\chad\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.0\\ArcCatalog\\anrc_water (anrcuser).sde"
>>> fdlist = arcpy.ListDatasets()
>>> for fd in fdlist:
...     print fd
... 
anrc_water.DBO.ChadTest
anrc_water.DBO.Temp_Data
anrc_water.DBO.Master_Datasets
ANRC_WATER.DBO.ENF_FILL_FACC
ANRC_WATER.DBO.ENF_FILL_FDIR

>>>
```

To get the path to my sde connection file, I just right-clicked on my SDE database in the Catalog tree, went to properties, then on the General tab, copy the path from the Name field:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir I got it now. i really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're using the Python window in ArcCatalog to create your scripts, you can drag & drop your connection into the Python window and it will format the path properly.

Comment: @TimothyMichael You just saved my life. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

Examples 3 through 5 on this page are amazing for this problem:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000q7000000

Here is a simplified version I made that lets me do on the fly connections in python using Sql Server direct connect only.

```
"""
Name: sdeconn.py
Description: Utility functions for sde connections
"""

# Import system modules
import arcpy, os, sys

def connect(database, server="<default server>", username="<default user>", password="<default password>", version="SDE.DEFAULT"):
    # Check if value entered for option
    try:
        #Usage parameters for spatial database connection to upgrade
        service = "sde:sqlserver:" + server 
        account_authentication = 'DATABASE_AUTH'
        version = version.upper()
        database = database.lower()

        # Check if direct connection
        if service.find(":") <> -1:  #This is direct connect
            ServiceConnFileName = service.replace(":", "")
            ServiceConnFileName = ServiceConnFileName.replace(";", "")
            ServiceConnFileName = ServiceConnFileName.replace("=", "")
            ServiceConnFileName = ServiceConnFileName.replace("/", "")
            ServiceConnFileName = ServiceConnFileName.replace("\\", "")
        else:
            arcpy.AddMessage("\n+++++++++")
            arcpy.AddMessage("Exiting!!")
            arcpy.AddMessage("+++++++++")
            sys.exit("\nSyntax for a direct connection in the Service parameter is required for geodatabase upgrade.")

        # Local variables
        Conn_File_NameT = server + "_" + ServiceConnFileName + "_" + database + "_" + username    

        if os.environ.get("TEMP") == None:
            temp = "c:\\temp"   
        else:
            temp = os.environ.get("TEMP")

        if os.environ.get("TMP") == None:
            temp = "/usr/tmp"       
        else:
            temp = os.environ.get("TMP")  

        Connection_File_Name = temp + os.sep + Conn_File_NameT + ".sde"
        if os.path.isfile(Connection_File_Name):
            return Connection_File_Name

        # Check for the .sde file and delete it if present
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True


        # Variables defined within the script; other variable options commented out at the end of the line
        saveUserInfo = "SAVE_USERNAME" #DO_NOT_SAVE_USERNAME
        saveVersionInfo = "SAVE_VERSION" #DO_NOT_SAVE_VERSION


        print "\nCreating ArcSDE Connection File...\n"
        # Process: Create ArcSDE Connection File...
        # Usage: out_folder_path, out_name, server, service, database, account_authentication, username, password, save_username_password, version,   save_version_info
        print temp
        print Conn_File_NameT
        print server
        print service
        print database
        print account_authentication
        print username
        print password
        print saveUserInfo
        print version
        print saveVersionInfo
        arcpy.CreateArcSDEConnectionFile_management(temp, Conn_File_NameT, server, service, database, account_authentication, username, password, saveUserInfo, version, saveVersionInfo)
        for i in range(arcpy.GetMessageCount()):
            if "000565" in arcpy.GetMessage(i):   #Check if database connection was successful
                arcpy.AddReturnMessage(i)
                arcpy.AddMessage("\n+++++++++")
                arcpy.AddMessage("Exiting!!")
                arcpy.AddMessage("+++++++++\n")
                sys.exit(3)            
            else:
                arcpy.AddReturnMessage(i)
                arcpy.AddMessage("+++++++++\n")
                return Connection_File_Name
    #Check if no value entered for option   
    except SystemExit as e:
        print e.code
        return
```

Using this script, I can make a connection file on the fly by simply calling:

```
import arcpy, sdeconn
myconnect1 = sdeconn.connect("database1", "server")
myconnect2 = sdeconn.connect("database2", "server")
```

This eliminates the problem of database connection files being inconsistent from machine to machine or user profile to user profile.

Comment: Great script, but I found a few minor issues with it during my development. 

 - It saves the password, but not as part of the file name, so when I supplied a different password the code found a connection file for the database but did not know the password was different. I changed the name to `md5.new( server + "_" + ServiceConnFileName + "_" + database + "-" + version + "_" + username + password).hexdigest()`
 - The indentation on the posting for the return is incorrect, so I didn't know my connection was failing.
 - The code changes the version to upper case, my version was lower case

Comment: Yeah, if I made the script now it would have some more options for things like forcing file creation (for when you change the password).

Answer (score 10):

You need to define your SDE connection document as you would normally in ArcCatalog; Then you will create the path to the layer in Python like this:

```
DataConnections = "C:\\AGS_GCSS_Tools\\DatabaseConnections\\" 
TCA_Connection = "prod_sde.sde\\prod_SDE.GIS.PropertyTax" + CAPSYear + "\\prod_SDE.GIS.Tca"
TCA_Layer = DataConnections + TCA_Connection
```

This will set your path to where your .SDE file lives, but then you set the path inside that connection to the layer you are looking for. In my case I also set a Year variable.

Comment: Hi Wright,Thanks for your response i really dont understand what you are saying, I need to run geoprocessing from my local desktop accessing my sde connection on a different server. I have connection created for the sde service on arc catalog. what should i do if want to access data from the sde connection.

Comment: Nowadays Esri recommends using os.path.join for joining the .sde connection file (sdeworkspace) variable and the object name. So it will be indata = os.path.join(sdeworkspace,"FeatureClass").

Answer (score 0):

you  can also define  the path of connection directly  in your Query .

```
PathSdeConnection= "C:\\Users\\{Username Of windows}\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.2\\ArcCatalog\\{name of ConenctionString}.sde
```

and use it  in Search  and etc.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(PathSdeConnection,("OBJECTID","SHAPE@","SHAPE@JSON"),{WhereClause})as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
                       .
                       .
                       .
```