# Extract an ArcSDE datasets (rasters/shapefiles) using Python?

Tags: python, enterprise-geodatabase, export

I would like to write a Python script to extract/export a dataset (rasters/shapefiles) in ArcSDE. I saw this posts to connect to the server:

[Define Workspace for SDE Connection in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16859/define-workspace-for-sde-connection-in-python)

But how can I extract the dataset?

Comment: You will probably use Make Feature Layer, Select Layer By Attribute/Location (or set arcpy.env.extent), and Copy Features.  Perhaps post your code so far to encourage assistance.