# arcpy.ListFeatureClasses returns empty list

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase

I'm working with SDE connection and want to find if a layer exists on a server. Code sample is:

```
ws = r'Database Connections\Connection to sde-srv.sde'
# second option to access connection file, same result
# ws = r'c:\Users\CurrentUser\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\Connection to sde-srv.sde'

arcpy.env.workspace = ws
fcs = []
for fd in arcpy.ListDatasets():
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset = fd):
        fcs.append(fc)
print fcs  # []
```

The problem is that everything is OK if I run this in ArcMap console (fcs contains all the FCs from server), but when runnig it in a standalone script outside the ArcMap app SDE seems to be empty.

On top of it running this script with x32 Python crashes with Win error. With x64 it just returns empty list.

Listing any other sources (GDBs and so on) works well in any case.

`arcpy.Exists(ws)` returns True in both cases.

***UPD**. It's not the same situation as described in 'possible duplicate' question (and few others that I've checked before with almost the same title). There is no problem with full/relative path, absence of FC/FD, encodings, priveleges ...

***UPD2** Win10, ArcGIS 10.2.2.3552, both x32 and x64 (Background processing) Python interpreters installed. 
RDBMS: Oracle 11g (seems to be 11.2.0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arcpy ListFeatureClasses in same workspace differs when run from ArcMap VS IDLE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119379/arcpy-listfeatureclasses-in-same-workspace-differs-when-run-from-arcmap-vs-idle)

Comment: Not a duplicate :( There is no issue with full or relative paths, both don't work.

Comment: Another thread [here](https://community.esri.com/thread/116986). may be its a permission issue as discussed?

Comment: I have full access (select/insert/update/delete). Connection file is not hidden. I've tried to copy it to other location and reference it and got the same result. Also on another machine with the same connection everything works fine.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact version of ArcGIS  (at this long remove, you should be using the terminal10.2.2 with dozens of patches), the exact RDBMS version, how the RDBMS client library has been configured, and the contents of your PATH environment variable.

Comment: @SergeNorin so are you saying that your code works without error on another machine, but not the one you are using? Sounds like it could be  virus protection software or firewall blocking a connection?

Comment: Have you tried setting ws to the feature dataset? Do you have any feature classes in the root ws that should be showing up or are all feature classes stored in datasets?

Comment: How about `datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []` check https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5893/listing-all-feature-classes-in-file-geodatabase-including-within-feature-datase

Comment: Does anything in this Esri tech support article help?  https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011504