# Register folder with ArcGIS Server without copying files

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-enterprise, arcgis-data-store

I can't opt for *"same as publisher folder path*" for the server path in the server manager. When I do, it says "directory path not valid. Cannot access this storage location (free translation!)" upon saving.

[image: ![enter image description here]

ESRI says: *"Use this scenario (same folder), if you want to avoid having a copy of the data placed on one of the ArcGIS Server machines..."*  https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/manage-data/windows/overview-register-data-with-arcgis-server.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_781E94B0D808448EBC8CB920E2A6C133

and
*"If the data does not reside on the ArcGIS Server machine and you use a local Windows account as the ArcGIS Server account, you must create an identical local account (having the same username and password) on the machine that hosts the data. Next, you must grant that local account access to the folders containing the source file. As long as the local accounts on the machine with data and the ArcGIS Server machine are identical, the ArcGIS Server machine can access the data."*
https://bkggis-tl1.bkg/hosting/help/en/server/11.1/manage-data/windows/making-your-data-accessible-to-arcgis-server.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_5AA7B6E854A341C986B1C2344D7CE9B3

Our IT-Administrator finds this very strange, is it really necessary to create this identical account?

Comment: I don't know what's going on in that first screen shot, but that path is 100% not right. `\\lsv649\d:\fileshare`  -- that's like a mash up of a local and UNC path in one.

Comment: I had that suspicion. lsv649 ist the server name. D:\ is the drive where the data sits. How do I need to write it?

Comment: See this link. After you've shared the folder, it shows how you would access it in step #5 https://pureinfotech.com/setup-network-file-sharing-windows-10/  Basically go to the folder you've shared and get to the properties > share and copy the link as it's shown

Comment: working with this folder now, how do I publish a GP Service? Coz to publish I need to run a tool locally, for which I need the local path with the drive letter as input for GP functions. However, the server will need the UNCs...do I have to change the path manually in the sript on the server? I still actually have not found where to find the published scripts.

Comment: correction: When I run a tool locally, and its script contains the shared UNC path, it prints a warning that the path, now turned into non-UNC format, ist not registered (upon publishing analysis).

Comment: You just need to pick 1 method and build it. If you tool uses local paths (`d:\myData`), then you put that path into your _publisher_ part on the data store. And assuming the Server references the data from UNC (`\\lsv649\myData`), then match that path to the 2nd part in your data store entry. OR -- during analyze, let the analyzer help you make the data store entry; it should create the appropriate one.

Comment: you need to use D$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per:

> Our IT-Administrator finds this very strange, is it really necessary
> to create this identical account?

Yes - depending on where the data is in relation to the GIS Server, *and* how the GIS Server is running.

Assume you have:

**Machine 1**  = GIS Server, running under a local account "Arcgis"

**Machine 2** = holds the data ArcGIS Server needs to access. (Meaning, you do NOT want to copy the data locally to the server, you want it to use the data from this location)

Well, the Server, running under "Arcgis" account needs permissions to ACCESS the data on another machine. It can do this by creating a mirrored account on your file server machine ("Arcgis" with the same password). When it reaches across the UNC connection (`\\myserver\filedata\`), windows allows it to do this assuming you've have that matching account on your file server AND you've **shared** and set **security** permissions.

Instances when this is NOT necessary:

- The data lives on the Server machine. You may have a mirrored copy on your local machine, but server will use it's own copy of the data, local to it.
- Your GIS Server is running under a domain account. In this case, you do not need to create a mirrored account on your file server machine. You just need to assign that domain account both the **share** and **security** permissions.

Answer (score 0):

As @KHibma pointed out in the comment, it was because of the wrong UNC path, the correct is

\LSV649\FileShare_AGE

(\ServerName\FolderName)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are doing, however, you need to use D$ in the file path. That is a true UNC path format i.e. \servername\d$\path\folder